# Discord.js interaction won't update

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a message with 3 buttons and I want to disable all 3 of the buttons after they have been clicked.

```
handle: async function(interaction) {

        interaction.deferUpdate();

        let components = interaction.message.components[0].components.forEach(c => {
            c.setDisabled(true)
        })

        await interaction.message.edit({embeds: interaction.message.embeds, components: components})
        // Do some other stuff
}

I have tried it with
```

interaction.update()

```
and multiple other ways but i can't get it to work.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you deferred your reply with [`.deferReply()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=deferReply) or [`.deferUpdate()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=deferUpdate) you need to use [`.editReply()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=editReply)

Code @ [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#deferring-and-updating-the-button-message)

```
collector.on('collect', async i => {
    if (i.customId === 'primary') {
        await i.deferUpdate();
        await wait(4000);
        await i.editReply({ content: 'A button was clicked!', components: [] });
    }
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. I don't want to edit the reply, I want to edit the components of the message with the ButtonInteraction.

Comment: Update: Your answer helped me fix a fatal mistake that I made and actually made my aproach work. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad i could help!